# JQuery: Is there any possibility to get the end of an animation?

Tags: jquery, animation

Here is my animation:

> ```
>   $(".ImageRoller ul").animate({
>     'marginLeft' : "-"+ScrollWidth+"px"
>     },Speed 
>     );
> ```

Now i want to make an alert or something when the animation ends. Is that even possible?

Chears
Vali

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".ImageRoller ul").animate (
    {
        'marginLeft' : "-"+ScrollWidth+"px"
    },
    {
        duration: Speed,
        complete: function () { doSomething (); }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate) you could define a callback function which will be called once the animation ends:

> animate( params, [duration], [easing],
>   [callback] )

```
$(".ImageRoller ul").animate(
    {'marginLeft' : "-"+ScrollWidth+"px"},
    Speed, 
    'linear', 
    function() {
        alert('animation end');
    }
);
```

Comment: It's actually (or should be, internally) the same - jQuery `animate` accepts both types of calls